# Task details are being saved into database but links details between task are not being saved

Tags: php, mysql, json

Since i changed the code

FROM (note that this part of the code was saving both task and link details):

```
$res=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("gantt"); 
$gantt = new JSONGanttConnector($res);
$gantt->render_links("gantt_links","id","source,target,type");
$gantt->render_table("gantt_tasks","id","start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent");
```

TO :

```
$connector = new JSONGanttConnector($res);
function default_values($action){
global $user_id;
$action->add_field("userId", $user_id);            
}
$connector->event->attach("beforeProcessing","default_values");   
$connector->render_sql("select * from gantt_tasks where userId = ".$user_id,"id","start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent");
$connector->render_sql("select * from gantt_links where userId = ".$user_id,"id","source,target,type");
$connector ->render_links("gantt_links","id","source,target,type,userId");
$connector->render_table("gantt_tasks","id","start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent,userId");
```

It only saves task details but not links detail between task. I dont understand why? As if it ignores the second render_mysql in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a valid construction-

```
$connector->render_sql("select * from gantt_tasks where userId = ".$user_id,"id","start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent");
$connector->render_sql("select * from gantt_links where userId = ".$user_id,"id","source,target,type");
$connector ->render_links("gantt_links","id","source,target,type,userId");
$connector->render_table("gantt_tasks","id","start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent,userId");
```

render_table/render_sql is expected to be only once per connector, so I don't know how your code works now.

Since you need to apply a configuration to links, you can initialize links connector explicitly.
This code

```
$dbtype = "MySQL";

$gantt = new JSONGanttConnector($res, $dbtype);

$gantt->render_links("gantt_links", "id", "source,target,type");
$gantt->render_table("gantt_tasks","id","start_date,duration,text,progress,parent","");
```

is equivalent to this:

```
$gantt = new JSONGanttConnector($res, $dbtype);

$links = new JSONGanttLinksConnector($res, $dbtype);
$links->render_table("gantt_links", "id", "source,target,type");
$gantt->set_options("links", $links);

$gantt->render_table("gantt_tasks","id","start_date,duration,text,progress,parent","");
```

As for filtering by user_id, I think following should do:

```
function default_values($action){
    global $user_id;
    $action->add_field("userId", $user_id);
}

$gantt = new JSONGanttConnector($res);

$links = new JSONGanttLinksConnector($res);

$links->filter("userId", $user_id);
$links->event->attach("beforeProcessing","default_values");
$links->render_table("gantt_links", "id", "source,target,type,userId");
$gantt->set_options("links", $links);

$gantt->filter("userId", $user_id);
$gantt->event->attach("beforeProcessing","default_values");
$gantt->render_table("gantt_tasks","id","start_date,duration,text,progress,parent,userId");
```

Comment: $links->filter("userId", $user_id);
$links->event->attach("beforeProcessing","default_values");
$gantt->render_links("gantt_links", "id", "source,target,type,userId");


$gantt->filter("userId", $user_id);
$gantt->event->attach("beforeProcessing","default_values");
$gantt->render_sql("select * from gantt_tasks where userId = ".$user_id,"id","start_date,duration,text,progress,sortorder,parent");
$gantt->render_table("gantt_tasks","id","start_date,duration,text,progress,parent,userId");

Comment: this code works and it saves both task and link details in the table . but this time the problem is that in the gantt_links table , only userId is not being saved :/ .i cant understand why the userId is not being saved .. Can you help me to solve it?